# C++ writing to myArray[0] and setting myInt = myFloat, why is this working?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, static

I'm playing with a function to get used to some C++ syntax.
Now I think, I might have misunderstood:

I'm writing to a static (?) array I had defined as `myArray[0]` for experimenting.

So it seems NOT to be static, but `sizeof(myArray)` always returns 0 (?)
but I can find mem address for each item (while I have no idea, how to get the number of items this way).

The other thing I don't understand, is why I can write `myInt = myFloat`?

So, what IS a static array? And should I better use `<vector>` for an array of undefined length?

(You could find the whole code here [int2bin main.cpp](https://replit.com/@BarbWire1/int2bin#main.cpp))

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <regex>



int main()
{
  while(true) {
      //VARS
      unsigned int arrBin[0], intNum; //working, if set [0]! NOT static???
      unsigned int *pArr0 = &arrBin[0];
      unsigned int *pArr1 = &arrBin[1];
      std::cout << sizeof(arrBin) << '\n'; // 0 => sizeof() here items and not mem space?
      std::cout << pArr0 << '\n';// 0x7fff12de6c38
      std::cout << pArr1 << '\n';// 0x7fff12de6c3c
      int i; 
      float refNum;
     
      std::cout << "\n\nEnter a number to convert: "; 
      
      // GET INPUT
      std::cin >> refNum; // float
      intNum = refNum;    // get int of the dec for comparing. Why does this "int = float" work???
```

Comment: The standard [doesn't permit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) arrays of size zero and it seems that `&arrBin[i]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: hmmm, but the size zero is working in that online editor and also in VSCode. strange...
(I only set it so, to see, what might happen, where I'd find the data)
And what do you mean re &arrBin[i]? @Evg

Comment: It's not strange that some compilers permit certain things that the ISO C++ standard doesn't. These are called compiler-specific extensions.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks, I didn't know that. New to compiled languages

Comment: C++ has a strict type system. If you want to convert a floating-point number to an integer, you can for example use an explicit cast, such as `myInt = static_cast<int>(myFloat);`. Or you can for example use one of the [rounding functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round). Some of these take a floating-point number as a parameter and return an integer, so you don't need to perform a cast.

Comment: Never judge things by "is working" (or not). Some actions (like writing or reading out of bounds) are illegal but hard or impossbile to detect. Instead they cause undefined behavior, that is, anything might happen. Your program could crash, throw an expcetion or appear to work.

Comment: ouch! thanks @AndreasWenzel, and @-churill.
Actually, I would not write like that. (strange enough ts wouldn't even allow it, and I thought C++ were much more strict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm writing to a static (?) array I had defined as myArray[0] for experimenting.

By 'static' you probably mean 'fixed-sized'. `static` means something totally different, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/.

> So it seems NOT to be static

It is not `static`, hence, it's not surprising that it's not `static`.

> but sizeof(myArray) always returns 0

Its size is 0, as the size of 0 was specified. While this is not supported by the standards, it's possible that some compilers allow it.

> but I can find mem address for each item (while I have no idea, how to get the number of items this way).

`&arr[i]` yields the address.

> The other thing I don't understand, is why I can write myInt = myFloat?

Integer numbers are always real numbers, but real numbers are not always integer numbers. So, how would you store 0.5 as an integer? You could cast it or you could round it.

> So, what IS a static array?

In the link I have provided you, it is mentioned that `static` variables in a function are variables for whom memory is allocated for the whole duration of a program. Hence, a `static` array is an array declared with the `static` keyword for which space are allocated for the whole lifecycle of your program. No such array was declared in your function.

> And should I better use  for an array of undefined length?

This is opinionated. You could create a pointer and navigate to items using [pointer arithmetics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm), achieving the same behavior as with arrays, but without the length being fixed and with a slightly different syntax. Or you could use a library, a `vector` or whatever fits your task and taste.

Comment: Thanks for the info! (re float/int, I actually need both exactly like that, just wondered why it seemed to work without casting them actively - but now learned never to do implicit conversions)
And thanks for the great link!

Comment: @BarbWire you are welcome. Implicity conversions are safe as long as you cast a float to an int, as all integers are real numbers as well at the same time, so there should be no issue to recognize an integer as a real number. However, the invert, that is, float to int may result in precision loss and it is a good practice to actively ensure that the behavior is the one you desire rather than the one the compiler assumes you desire. But this is only applicable when precision loss or conversion difficulties are involved.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> unsigned int arrBin[0]
> ```

The size of an array variable must not be 0. The program is ill-formed. Don't do this.

> ```
> unsigned int *pArr1 = &arrBin[1];
> ```

Here, you use subscript operator beyond the bounds of the array (beyond one past last element), so the behaviour of the program is undefined. Don't do this.

> (while I have no idea, how to get the number of items this way).

The number of items is 0 (or would be if that was allowed in the first place).

> The other thing I don't understand, is why I can write myInt = myFloat?

You haven't even declared such identifiers.

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't do that in a real piece of code; I just "play" around to understand how thinks work in C++..
And `myInt = myFloat`doesn't mean the varName, but the type of them as the daclaration is not included in this snippet. sorry, if my question was misleading